# Normals at the end

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am reading a research paper "Embedded minimal surface with an infinite number of ends" by Callahan etc. In this paper they said "Since we are interested in embedded surfaces, the normals at the ends are all parallel and they are all vertical". What do they mean by normals at the end and how are normals at the ends are all parallel?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Heuristically, two distinct ends will look, at infinity, as flat portions of a plane, and if you don't want them to cross each other (the surface is embedded), they will have to be parallel.

Comment: Start with the definition of ends of the surface?

Comment: @Didier I just started reading all this...sorry if I am asking some stupid question. As you said "if you don't want them to cross each other, the surface is embedded". My doubt is: 1) Is this true that every embedded surface doesn't cross each other? 2.And, If it is not true for every embedded surface then what is the additional condition for not crossing each other?

Comment: @Infy An embedded surface does not cross **itself**: in the definition of an embedding $f\colon S\to \Bbb R^3$, it is required that $f$ is an homeomorphism onto its image, and particularly, an injective map. Since two distinct ends of an embedded surface are part of this surface, they can't cross each other

Comment: @Didier thank you